# Iterate through sub child node in xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

MY config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Config>

  <GetPollingIndexDetails>
    <NoRunDays>Sunday,Sunday</NoRunDays>
    <Times>07:00</Times>
    <Friday>Friday</Friday>
    <ServiceTimerInterval>1</ServiceTimerInterval>
    <RequestValueUserName>test</RequestValueUserName>
    <RequestValuePassword>test</RequestValuePassword>

    <NASPATH_LOC>
      <NASPATH>
        <NASPath>D:\NSEFiles</NASPath>
        <NASUserId>abc</NASUserId>
        <UserDomain>abc</UserDomain>
        <NASUserPwd>abc</NASUserPwd>
        <LoginType>9</LoginType>
        <FileNamePattern>NCDEX_INDEX_ddMMyyyy[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{2}$</FileNamePattern>
      </NASPATH>
      <NASPATH>
        <NASPath>D:\NSEFiles</NASPath>
        <NASUserId>abc</NASUserId>
        <UserDomain>abc</UserDomain>
        <NASUserPwd>abc</NASUserPwd>
        <LoginType>9</LoginType>
        <FileNamePattern>NCDEX_INDEX_ddMMyyyy[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{2}$</FileNamePattern>
      </NASPATH>
    </NASPATH_LOC>

    <MailFrom>nse_dev@ncdex.com</MailFrom>
    <EmailToExtranet>nse_dev@ncdex.com</EmailToExtranet>
  </GetPollingIndexDetails>

  <FUTINDEX>
    <INDEX>FUTXX</INDEX>
    <DisplayName>NCDEX </DisplayName>
  </FUTINDEX>
</Config>
```

I am trying to iterate through nodes under NASPATH_LOC for each NASPATH but struggling to even get to the first node. but I am not able to get a parent node too . it is giving null value in return. any kind of help will be grateful.

```
_xmlConfigPath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigXML"]);

XmlDocument xmlNasNode = new XmlDocument(); //added for test 
xmlNasNode.Load(_xmlConfigPath);
XmlNodeList xnList = xmlNasNode.SelectNodes("/GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList);
{
    string NASPath = logwritter.GetMessage("//GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH/NASPath", _xmlConfigPath);
    string NASUserId = logwritter.GetMessage("//GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH/NASUserId", _xmlConfigPath);
    string UserDomain = logwritter.GetMessage("//GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH/UserDomain", _xmlConfigPath);
    string NASUserPwd = logwritter.GetMessage("//GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH/NASUserPwd", _xmlConfigPath);
    int LoginType = Convert.ToInt32(logwritter.GetMessage("//GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH/LoginType", _xmlConfigPath));
}
```

Comment: you forgot Config...  /Config/GetPollingIndexDetails/NASPATH_LOC/NASPATH

Comment: @owairc Oh!! that was a silly one . Thanks !!